# How can I combine JQuery selectors and variables to shorten code for easier scaleability?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have this piece of javascript that is working.

```
var footerColour = $.color.extract($("div#one.footer"), 'background-color');
var newrgba = $.color.parse(footerColour).add('a', -0.5).toString()
$("div#one.footer").css("background-color", ''+ newrgba +'');

var navColour = $.color.extract($("div#two.nav"), 'background-color');
var newrgba1 = $.color.parse(navColour).add('a', -0.5).toString()
$("div#two.nav").css("background-color", ''+ newrgba1 +'');
```

It is checking two different divs for a colour and changing the css colour value with the returned colour from a jQuery colour plugin that I have. I plan to continue to add more of these, but figured this could probably be written out in a more compact or combined way to allow for more items to be added without repeating the same three lines of code each time.

I have looked into arrays, but have been unable to find the exact answer and syntax to help with this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Given the amount of code like this (http://uglyjs.net/2011/09/17/omg-jquery/), jQuery should consider caching their selectors internally (with optional revalidation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the colour change stuff in a function and then call the function with each id (or selector) that you want to apply it to:

```
function changeBackground(selector) {
   var footerColour = $.color.extract($(selector), 'background-color');
   var newrgba = $.color.parse(footerColour).add('a', -0.5).toString();
   $(selector).css("background-color", ''+ newrgba +'');
}

changeBackground("div#one.footer");
changeBackground("div#two.nav");
changeBackground("add other item here");

// or pass them all at once
changeBackground("div#one.footer, div#two.nav, etc");
// or give them all a common class and pass that
changeBackground(".someCommonClass");
```

If you used the latter options to update all at once you should probably loop through each item matching the selector and update them one by one (otherwise either it wouldn't work or they'd all end up with the same colour):

```
function changeBackground(selector) {
   $(selector).each(function() {
      var footerColour = $.color.extract($(this), 'background-color');
      var newrgba = $.color.parse(footerColour).add('a', -0.5).toString();
      $(this).css("background-color", ''+ newrgba +'');
   });
}
```

Note: given that ID is supposed to be unique, you can select just on the id. so `$("#one")` instead of `$("div#one.footer")` - unless you want to select on that id only when it has the "footer" class.

Comment: Thank you nnnnnn! That works perfect, and yes, it does return the same color unless matching the selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a common class to the elements which need to see these changes and use the following code:

Assuming common class is 'changeBG'

```
jQuery('.changeBG').each(function() {
  var navColor = jQuery.color.extract(jQuery(this), 'background-color');
  var newRGBA = jQuery.color.parse(navColor).add('a', -0.5).toString();
  jQuery(this).css("background-color", ''+ newRGBA +'');
});
```

This should solve shorten your code.

Comment: Thanks GeekTantra! This also worked! Would this or nnnn's solution be the more "correct" way of doing things or is this just preference? I am curious just for learning purposes. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion this would be a better approach since we are not using additional procedures directly, keeping the code much shorter and precise.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
function changeColor(arr, colorType){

    // Define length of array
    var i = arr.length;

    // Loop over each item in array
    while(i--){

        // Create jQuery object with element from array
        var $elem = $( arr[i] );

        // Run the color change logic
        var color = $.color.extract($elem, colorType);
        var newColor = $.color.parse(color).add('a', -0.5).toString();
        $elem.css(colorType, newColor);

    }

}

// Array of jQuery selectors
var elems = ["div#one.footer","div#two.nav"];

// Pass array and color type to changeColor function
changeColor(elems, "background-color");
```

This function takes an array of strings that must be valid jQuery selectors and a `colorType` which could be anything with color (I assume your plugin supports more than just `background-color`).

**EDIT**

Ooops, I had an incorrect variable name in there. It was `$elem.css(colorType, color);` but it should have been `$elem.css(colorType, newColor);`.

Anyway, this function gives you greater flexibility because you can change the color type in the function call. You would execute one function per array and just specify a color type. You could easily add another parameter for `colorChange` to handle the `'a', -0.5` part.

This method also results in fewer function calls which would likely make it faster than the other solutions here.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bryan. I am new to jquery/javascript, and wasn't able to get this to work for me. I'm sure I may be missing something easy (eg-not just copy and paste), but I can't really follow the code to diagnose. But again, thank you for the response!

Comment: @Darbis - I made some edits. Hopefully it makes a bit more sense now.